# intercommunication between Primefaces components from different JSF pages which are inserted in one same page?

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces

I have Primefaces JSF pages and I need  help understanding how to communicate between PF components.

I have folllowing PF JSF pages

1. nav.xhtml
   NavBean.java
2. display_table.xhml
   DisplayTableBean.java
3. display_detail_table.xhtml
   DisplayDetailTable.java
4. index.xhtml

Inside of index.xhtml, I am using facelet tags to insert pages.

```
    <div id="menu">
        <ui:insert name="nav">
            <ui:include src="navigation.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content">
            <ui:include src="display.xhtml" />
            <ui:include src="display2.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
```

Question is ,

When I select something from navigation tree, I want to fire up event and pass selected node(data) to the displayTable and DisplayDetail.

I am confused how I need to handle creating event and registering those events.
Any example code will be greatly appreciaed.

Do I manage from javascript in index page?
Each page has  tags inside.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: is the question how to pick up the navigation event in the backing bean, or is it how to get the navigation state from one bean to the other?

Comment: how to get the navigation state from one bean to the other.

Comment: use dependency injection to inject one bean into the other, then manipulate the state of the other been from the method that handles the navigation event. Here is a tutorial for jsf 2.0 using ManagedBeans: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/